# Overcoming domain access issues with Webbrowser Control in MS Access

Tags: javascript, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, webbrowser-control

I've developed a database application in MS Access 2010 that has an embedded WebBrowser Control which is used to view a local web page.  The page uses the Google Maps API to provide some unique mapping capabilities and I use the web browser control to access javascript in the webpage to pass map data between the database and the webpage that renders it.

However, I've been running into the "Access is Denied" cross-domain error that I can't resolve.  I recall addressing this before, and it involved adding a "Mark of the Web" comment and ensuring the appropriate IE compatibility mode - both of which I've done.

The HTML file is locally loaded, and it includes a series of javascript files in a separte folder (also local).  The javascript files use the google maps API to populate the map in the web browser control

Anyway, see below for the index.html file that the webbrowser control directly loads inside MS Access.  There's a lot of code overall, so I don't want to spam the thread until I have a better idea of what I should be looking for.

Incidentally, I am using an HTMLWindowProxy object from within VBA to directly call the loaded javascript functions embedded in the web pages.

Specifically, from within VBA, I call:

```
Call proxyWindow.execScript mScriptName
```

or

```
Call proxyWindow.Navigate mScriptName
```

It's this call that generates the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=edge”><meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=edge”>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

      .gm-style-iw {
        min-width: 150px; 
      }      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pathData">
      <input type="hidden" id="docReadyState" value="unset">
      <input type="hidden" id="default_position" 
             data-lat=41.843435 data-lng=-89.481619>

      <input type="hidden" id="location_address" value="">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry&key=REDACTED"></script>

    <script src="js/html.js"></script>
    <script src="js/BindableBase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mvcarraybinder.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ButtonControl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ElementOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SectionMarker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SectionPolyline.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/SectionMap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                document.getElementById ("docReadyState").value = "ready";}
            else {
                document.getElementById("docReadyState").value = "busy";}
        }
    </script>
</body>
```